# 16.04 to 18.04 made my system unusable

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have been working happily in Ubuntu 16.04. This morning, the update icon offered me an upgrade to 18.04.

Since I have upgraded several times before, without problem, I went ahead. Very soon, there were many, many alerts saying things failed. I could not get control back in the UI.

I was able to get a login shell by selecting a recovery kernel. However, no apt, apt-get, or dpkg commands work.

I downloaded an 18.04 iso file, with the idea of making a DVD and installing from that. Not sure if that's the best way to go, though.

At least I have my home directory.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I would run a live cd and get all your files off onto a thumb drive or hard drive before anything else.  Then a fresh install of 18.04 is the best.  The direct upgrade is usually not recommended till the first point release.  18.04.1 which comes in July or August.

Comment: I hope they tell everyone this @walttheboss!

Comment: Much appreciated, @walttheboss. I'm ashamed to admit I'm a bit confused by "running a live cd". Maybe I'm just a bit muddled from tangling with this all day. Is that just synonymous with booting off the .iso in its CD or DVD or USB incarnation?

Comment: Yes, @walttheboss is advising you to preserve your data, then (and only then) nuke your broken system and re-install  afresh. It's good advice if you lack the skills to troubleshoot the problem further.

Comment: Thank you @user535733! Of course I'd like to have those skills, but then there would be the time tradeoff between acquiring said skills, and getting back on a working Linux system.

Comment: And, @George Udosen, I hope that as well.

Comment: Okay. 2 days later. Thanks to the excellent advice from @walttheboss and user535733, I am back up and running. Soooo ... FIRST, per advice, I saved my home directory (straightforward, but not trivial by any means due mainly to size ... wireless would stall after a while, so I had to use ethernet and an external hard drive). Then, with a DVD burned from an official Ubuntu 18.04 desktop .iso file, I started in on that clean install. Soon I was up and running. Just had to carefully tweak for chrome bookmarks etc.  ... apt'd emacs, gcc, etc.. All seem to work, knock on wood. Thanks again, gang!

Comment: It only let me reference '@' one other user. I referenced walttheboss thusly  in the previous comment. So, thank you walttheboss and @user535733. You too, George.